# Williams p+1 integer factorization

Tags: python, algorithm, integer, rsa, factorization

I am asked to introduce to my classmates the the Williams' p+1 algorithm to factor integers and I don't think I get it right. As far as I understand, this algorithm takes an integer N that factors into primes p,q (N=pq) where p+1 is B-smooth. I understand why, starting from these premises, the algorithm works (I've written proof), but I don't get how to correctly implement and use it. I think it must be implemented as follows:

1. I take a, randomly, in interval [1,N-1]
2. I compute x=gcd(a,N). If x !=1, then I return x (I don't get why we don't check first if x is prime because we don't actually know if N really is equal to p*q and x could be composed, right?)
3. Normally, x == 1, so I have to compute y = gcd(V_M-2,N) where V_0 = 2, V_1 = a, V_n= aV_(n-1) - V_(n-2) . I have found a way to compute V_n doing matrix power modulus N but I don't know which M should I use (I've copied the Pollard's one, but I don't know if that works and why).
4. If y!=1 and y!=N, I return y (again, as with the x, I think we should check that y is prime, am I right?). Else, just try another random a and start again.

So, that is mainly my question about the implementation, overall concerning the building of M, which might be related to the fact of p+1 B-smoothness I guess.

Regarding the usage, I really don't get in which cases I should use this method and which B should I take. I am going to leave my code in Python3 here and a case example that really is turning me crazy to see if you can give me a hand.

```
import random
from math import floor, log, gcd

def is_prime(n): #funcion que determina si un numero es primo
    for d in range(2,n):
        if n%d == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes_leq(B): #funcion para obtener los primos que son menor o igual que B
    l=[]
    for i in range(2,B+1):
        if is_prime(i):
            l.append(i)
    return l

def matrix_square(A, mod):
    return mat_mult(A,A,mod)


def mat_mult(A,B, mod):
  if mod is not None:
    return [[(A[0][0]*B[0][0] + A[0][1]*B[1][0])%mod, (A[0][0]*B[0][1] + A[0][1]*B[1][1])%mod],
            [(A[1][0]*B[0][0] + A[1][1]*B[1][0])%mod, (A[1][0]*B[0][1] + A[1][1]*B[1][1])%mod]]


def matrix_pow(M, power, mod):
    #Special definition for power=0:
    if power <= 0:
      return [[1,0],[0,1]]

    powers =  list(reversed([True if i=="1" else False for i in bin(power)[2:]])) #Order is 1,2,4,8,16,...

    matrices = [None for _ in powers]
    matrices[0] = M

    for i in range(1,len(powers)):
        matrices[i] = matrix_square(matrices[i-1], mod)

    result = None

    for matrix, power in zip(matrices, powers):
        if power:
            if result is None:
                result = matrix
            else:
                result = mat_mult(result, matrix, mod)

    return result

def williams(N, B):
    flag = False
    while not flag :
        a = random.randint(1,N-1)
        print("a : " + str(a))
        x = gcd(a,N)
        print("x : " + str(x))
        if x != 1:
            return x
        else :
            M = 1
            A = [[0,1],[-1,a]]
            
            for p in primes_leq(B):
                M *= p **(floor(log(N,p)))
            print("voy por aquí")
            
            C = matrix_pow(A,M,N)
            V = 2*C[0][0]+ a*C[0][1]
            y = gcd(V-2,N)
            print("y : " + str(y))
            if y != 1 and y != N:
                flag = True
    return y
```

Trying to test my implementation, I've tried to follow some examples to check if my factorization is working alright. For example, I've looked at https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/records/Pplus1.html and I've tried `williams(2**439-1,10**5)` and I'm getting 104110607 but I understand I should be getting  122551752733003055543 (as in the webpage). As far as I understand, both are primes that factor N=2**439-1, but isn't this fact just contradicting the hypothesis of N being a product of two primes p*q?

Thanks for your help, it'll be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point of this algorithm...

You find a factor *p* of N (or a trivial divisor) when *M* is a multiple of *p+1*.

If *p+1* is smooth -- say all the factors of *p+1* are <= B -- then it becomes becomes possible to construct an *M* that is a multiple of *all* such possible factors, like this:

```
M=1
for x in all primes <= B:
    let y = largest power of x such that y < N
    M = M*y
```

You should check the successive values of M produced by this loop.  Alternatively you could just check all successive factorials.  The point is that, in each iteration, you add new factors to *M*, and when all the factors of *p+1* are in *M*, then *M* will of course be a multiple of *p+1*.

The tricky part is that *M* will very get large, and you can't take *M* mod *N*.  What you can do, though, is calculate all the *V<sub>M</sub>* mod *N*, and instead of actually calculating each *M*, you just multiply the subscript of *V<sub>M</sub>* by the appropriate factor using the addition formula:  *V<sub>a+b</sub>* = *V<sub>a</sub>V<sub>b</sub> - V<sub>a-b</sub>*

Comment: I appreciate your answer too but I really don't feel yet responded to all the questions that I threw. At least I know now that I constructed my M properly (since I did the same thing you've written), but I don't get how I should choose the B and to which numbers should I apply this method

Comment: If you don't know beforehand that N has a factor with that particular bound, B is just how long you're willing to let the algorithm run.  You would apply this algorithm to all numbers for which faster, simpler algorithms fail.

Comment: Do you think my implementation is then alright? Because I'm not sure and I'm afraid that it won't work when I am asked to use it.

Comment: No!  It looks like it should work, but it looks like it's a lot slower and takes a lot more memory than it should.  As I said in my answer, M will get very large, and you should not be constructing it at all.  You should be calculating V_m mod N only.

Comment: It can't be good because I've tried williams(124342547396734967549359746795934695543694985,10**3) and it returns 2957935 which is not prime

Comment: If N has more than 2 prime factors, Williams' method may return a composite factor.  This is especially true when you don't check V_m on each iteration of the above loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239209/discussion-between-nuria-gallego-arino-and-matt-timmermans).

Answer (score 0):

2<sup>439</sup>−1 has more than two prime factors. If you’re not getting
the one you want, you should divide by the one that you got and keep
going on the quotient.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but your answer doesn't respond to half of the things that I asked. But I'm going to do that in the meanwhile.

Comment: @NuriaGallegoAriño If you find a nontrivial factor f of a semiprime n, then f and n/f are both guaranteed to be prime, which answers your other questions.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've lack of vocabulary to understand this issue. I guess semiprime refers to the fact that N is product of two primes, but that's just the hypothesis, how do I know that is actually true? I don't have N factorization. Indeed, I've got a factor of 2^439-1 and you have told me that it has more than two prime factors indeed